# Camera randomly re-connects to PC

Tags: camera, firewire

I don't know if it's the right place to post this question or I should go to StackOverflow, but I'll give it a try.

I've got my camera connected to PC. It works just fine. But sometimes, let's say every 10 minutes, it 're-connects' to the computer which makes a process of capturing a video from a tape impractical.

I'm sure that the camera works fine by itself, because on the other computer everything works fine. I know that in order to find the core of the problem I should check if the cable is not damaged first or if there is something wrong with Firewire adapter card inside the computer, but I do not have access to a second cable or card.

So is there any programmatical way to find out what the problem may be?

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you have another computer entirely that it works on, then you know that the cable is good.  This means it must be the firewire card or drivers on the PC that isn't working that is messed up.  I'd first try uninstalling/reinstalling the firewire card and drivers and if that doesn't work, I'd try a new card.